# Nan from consol.log

Tags: javascript, nan

When looping through my array objects in the console I get `nan`

why is this? Also what can I do to get the actual values?

```
lineArr.forEach(function(arrayItem) {
    var x = arrayItem.prop1 + 2;
    console.log(x);
});
```

Comment: I believe you have confused Java with Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nan - Not a Number.

To see what is in the array:

```
lineArr.forEach(function(arrayItem) {
    console.log(arrayItem);
});
```

The NaN is thrown into the console probably because you are trying to add a number to a non-numerical value on this line: `var x = arrayItem.prop1 + 2;`.
If for example the arrayItem.prop1 is actually a string value, such as "10", you could use  `var intValueOfProp1 = parseInt(arrayItem.prop1)`.

Comment: @NDiaz did this answer your question? If it did you could accept it. :) If it didn't then maybe you could clarify your problem some more.

Comment: Ya you fixed it, I understand its not a number but can you explain what I was saying that made it output nan?

Comment: Probably because you could've find the answer with a little bit of googling.

Comment: I know what nan is I didnt know why I was getting it but ok